# How to make an OS X app using pyinstaller on Windows PC?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I made a program using python, and easily made an exe file using pyinstaller.

I want to make an app for OS X too. Am I need to modify a spec file? Please tell me how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a Mac and then use the same process as you did on your PC. I'm not aware of any way of building a Mac app on a PC, I'm fairly sure this is against Apple's policy.